# Method get_context_data is called twice when using template tags in django

Tags: python, django

I have a template_tag.py:

```
from django import template

from myapp.views import RenderView

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("template_tag.html")
def render_myapp():
    rv=RenderView()
    return rv.get_context_data()
```

and myapp.views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
class RenderView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "test.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(RenderView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["test"] = 1 # this is hit twice in the debugger

        return context
```

template_tag.html:

```
{% if test %}
    {{ test|safe }}
{% endif %}
```

base.html (**different app**):

```
{% load template_tag %}
{% render_myapp %}
```

I wonder why `RenderView().get_context_data()` is hit twice in the debugger? I don't call it twice in my template. It's probably because `TemplateView` already calls get_context_data and then I call it again `rv.get_context_data()`. But then how should my `template_tag.py` look like to not call get_context_data() again?

Comment: Why do you want to call that method in your template tag at all? What's the point?

Comment: Briefly scanning your code, it looks odd that you are calling the super of RenderView with every request that your app receives. Consider initializing the super in __init__ and then using ```self.get_context_date(**kwargs)```.

Comment: @larsl That's normal when overriding methods. Note he is calling `super`'s `get_context_data`, not the `__init__`.

Comment: If you want to create an inclusion tag with all the context, you can use [`takes_context=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.inclusion_tag), but why not just use [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include), if all you are doing is returning the context? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218632/django-built-in-include-tag-vs-custom-inclusion-tag) for use cases.

Comment: @DanielRoseman because that method contains the variable `test` that I want in `template_tag.html`. If I remove  `return rv.get_context_data()`  then nothing displays.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida because if I include the template in a different app with `@include template_tag.html` then I don't get the variables from the app, like `test`. They appear as undefined.

Comment: You seem to have some big misunderstandings about template tags. They shouldn't have any relationship to views at all. If you're depending on a view to render your template tag, you're doing it wrong. You should define the context you need in the tag function, not in the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman probably, yes. So I should move the code from views.py into tag.py and then call the tag in views? I don't see how  takes_context=True is helping me if my main logic is in views.py

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga I think I finally understand what you're doing, but I agree with Daniel that it's an odd way to structure the code. If there is common logic/configuration you can extract it to a different file and use it from both the view and the template tag (i.e. you don't _have_ to put it in the view and call it from the tag or vice-versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two situations here.

In one case, the template tag is always in a template that is rendered by your RenderView. In which case, there doesn't seem to be any need for a tag; you should just either include template_tag.html or put its code directly into test.html.

In the other case, the tag is in another template, or in a range of templates that may or may not be rendered by RenderView. In which case, why is the context data for that page defined in RenderView? It should be defined directly in `render_myapp()`.

Comment: ok, I understand now. The reason why I put the tag logic in view was because I have to show each tag individually on different pages and then have another master page (different app) where I show them all together. So view1 will be tag1 view2 -> tag2 and then viewall -> all tags. So essentially I'll have pages where only its tag will show, so tag = view. But yeah, I'll just include the code in tag instead.