# Improve the function of a template tag - Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-templates

I am programming a star rating system, to calculate the stars graphically of a course, I used the following template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_course_rating(course):
    decimal, integer = math.modf(course.get_average_rating())

    rating_stars = {
        'stars': range(int(integer))
    }

    if decimal > 0:
        rating_stars['star_half_empty'] = True
        rating_stars['stars_empty'] = range((5 - int(integer)) - 1)
    else:
        rating_stars['star_half_empty'] = False
        rating_stars['stars_empty'] = range(5 - int(integer))

    return rating_stars
```

In this way I put the star rating in the HTML:

```
{% load course_tags %}
{% get_course_rating course as rating %}

{% for i in rating.stars %}
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
{% endfor %}

{% if rating.star_half_empty %}
    <i class="icon-star-half-alt"></i>
{% endif %}

{% for i in rating.stars_empty %}
    <i class="icon-star-empty"></i>
{% endfor %}
```

---

I find it very tedious to do that, so I wonder if there is a way to improve it? 
In the sense of the HTML.

I use this html code about 3 times and for me it's repetitive code and I don't want that ...

It occurs to me that the template tag returns html code but I am not sure if it is of good practice ...

Any much more professional solution? It will help my learning a lot ...

Comment: You can have this stars html as __separate template and __reuse it with [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include)__. Or make it into separate __[inclusion_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)__

Comment: The best solution was the inclusion tag !! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this `"start rating html"` as separate template and **reuse it with custom [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)**.

Another less dynamic option - **reuse with [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include)** in templates.

Difference [nicely described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14218982/12520350).

Comment: saved the file in the following path: `courses/snippets/rating_stars.html`. 
What do you think?

Comment: This `html` is template, so it should go to `templates` directory (subdirectory of your choice). Tag definitions - in [`templatetags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout).

Comment: I forgot to put the complete route, here it is: `courses/templates/courses/snippets/rating_stars.html`. It's okay like that? what do you think?

Comment: Yes, its ok. Directory layout is more of a personal taste, and should make senses to you. I.e., I prefer for django project with multiple apps - one common template dir (cause these templates define how my site looks like) (with sub-dirs for apps), so there is no templates in apps dirs. But, In this case - template is part of template tag and is not supposed to be used directly. Template tag is in some app. So, this template needs to be in this app dir/templates dir, not in common templates dir.

Comment: in a nutshell this template must be in the "templates" directory of the application, where is the template tag, right?

Comment: Yes, you got it